# No puedo quitar el error "Se han detectado errores de #include. Actualice el valor de includePath." Visual Studio Code y MinGW para C

Tags: c, visual, studio, headers

a ver si me podéis ayudar. Recientemente he empezado a usar Visual Studio Code para programar en lenguaje C. Aparte de este editor, como compilador he instalado MinGW.

Añado al PATH la ruta del compilador gcc, añado al fichero de configuración la ruta de los ficheros cabecera. Pero me sigue saliendo el error, no acabo de dar con la tecla de como evitarlo. Lo curioso es que solo me ocurre son el stdio.h, con el otro math.h no ocurre, lo puse ahí por probar simplemente.
A modo de ejemplo pongo este código simple:

[image]

y la configuración que tengo:
**texto en negrita**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado, y que alguien me diga donde puede estar el problema porque por más que he buscado no lo encuentro. Eso sí, el programa se ejecuta sin problemas, pero no quiero tener ese error porque no se si en el futuro me puede perjudicar.
Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Paso 1.** 
Haz click en el foco el cual te llevará a Configuraciones de IntelliSense
[image]
**Paso 2.**
Hacer Scroll hasta la siguiente opción "Ruta de acceso del compilador"
Y elegir el compilador de la lista 
[image]

Comment: Tenía el mismo problema. Y esta solución la encontré en el foro en inglés. Si quieres que siga respondiendo a dudas en este foro no votes negativo po o menos ya que en este foro por mi experiencia la gente muere ignorada sin respuestas.

Comment: Yo no he votado nada de nada!!

Comment: Es para la comunidad en general. Disculpa.